# Set particular value in DataFrame with interval index

Tags: python, pandas

Let I have a dataframe like this one:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
        0, 
        index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([100, 200, 300, 400]),
        columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
)
```

So it will give us this:

```
            A   B   C
(100, 200]  0   0   0
(200, 300]  0   0   0
(300, 400]  0   0   0
```

Now, suppose, I want to change particular value in given interval, having integer value in some of intervals I have in my dataframe.

I can get values of interval by `.loc` for particular given integer value by this weay:
`test_df.loc[250]`. This will give me series.

But!

*The first case*:

```
test_df.at[250, 'B']
------
ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers
```

Why can't I user integer value `250` in this case? It works great with integer type in `.loc`.

*The second case*:

```
test_df.loc[250, 'B']
------
'pandas._libs.interval.IntervalTree' object has no attribute 'get_value'
```

Has no attribute `get_value`? So how can I get value then? Can I do it only through series, by getting it via `.loc` property?

*The third case*:

```
test_df.at[250, 'B'] = 10
------
'pandas._libs.interval.IntervalTree' object has no attribute 'set_value'
```

**Main question**
How should I set particular value then in dataframe?

Comment: `test_df.loc[250].at['B']`

Comment: Then I can simply write `test_df.loc[250]['B'] = 10`

Answer (score 2):

`.loc` currently works if you provide it with a list for the second set of labels:

```
test_df.loc[250, ['B']]
#B    0
#Name: (200, 300], dtype: int64

test_df.loc[250:400, ['B', 'C']]
#            B  C
#(200, 300]  0  0
#(300, 400]  0  0

test_df.loc[250, ['B']] = 10
print(test_df)
#            A   B  C
#(100, 200]  0   0  0
#(200, 300]  0  10  0
#(300, 400]  0   0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the behavior with `loc` has been [fixed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/22576) and will be present in the upcoming 0.24.0 release:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.0.dev0+870.g7191af9b4'

In [2]: test_df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:         0,
   ...:         index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([100, 200, 300, 400]),
   ...:         columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
   ...: )

In [3]: test_df
Out[3]:
            A  B  C
(100, 200]  0  0  0
(200, 300]  0  0  0
(300, 400]  0  0  0

In [4]: test_df.loc[250, 'B']
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: test_df.loc[250, 'B'] = 100

In [6]: test_df
Out[6]:
            A    B  C
(100, 200]  0    0  0
(200, 300]  0  100  0
(300, 400]  0    0  0
```

Comment: Great! And nevertheless it was bug, if I understood it right. I think behavior of `.at` property should be fixed too.

Answer (score 1):

```
test_df.loc[250].at['B'] = whatever
```

but make sure whatever is the same type as column data type